# Reduce Image Size Before Uploading

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm trying to reduce image size at the client side before it is being uploaded to the server. I have the following javascript code to generate a reduced sized image of the selected file for upload.

```
function handleUpload(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    // from an input element
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        img.src = reader.result
        createCanvas(canvas, img);//method that creates a reduced sized canvas
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
}
```

How can I upload the resized Image file to the server in JSF. I have the following JSF tag which is creating the canvas, but still uploads the original file to the server.

```
<h:inputFile id="file" value="#{managedBean.uploadedFile}" onchange="handleUpload()"/>
```

PS:

Mojara 2.2

Comment: You may need to set the dataurl to the input file at the end of the handleUpload function